# Add-in Command Ribbon Disappearing Word for Mac

Tags: macos, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am working on an Office add-in that creates a tab using add-in commands. Everything works perfectly on Windows. Using the same manifest on Mac however, I run into some issues.

The tab is inserted fine when I open the add-in. I am able to use all the features as expected. However, When I close and reopen Word the tab created by the add-in disappears. On Windows the tab is maintained if I close and reopen Word.

I even tested using a sample add-in command manifest from Microsoft. I had the same issue there. The add-in appears in the appropriate tab but if I close and reopen Word it disappears.

Is this expected behavior? Is there some setting in Word that I need to change?

Thanks!

Before you ask I am using the latest version of Word (15.36) and am running on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5